# Salesforce form pass GA data

Tags: google-analytics, salesforce

I am using Salesforce's Web-to-lead feature. It basically creates a form that inputs the data in a new lead for every submission. I'm wondering how to dynamically populate the hidden fields in the code below (Refer Url, Landing Page URL, GA source / medium / campaign)

I tried the code suggested on [this blog post](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/integrate-salesforce-and-google-analytics), unsuccessfully.

This is what the html for the form loks like:

```html
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="/thankyou.html">

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="title">Title</label><input  id="title" maxlength="40" name="title" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<div style="display:none;">

<label for="lead_source">Lead Source</label><select  id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
<option value="Quotefx Web Inquiry" selected>Web Inquiry</option>
</select><br>

Refer URL:<input  id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" maxlength="255" name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" size="20" type="text" /><br>

Landing Pg URL:<input  id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" maxlength="255" name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" size="20" type="text" /><br>

GA Medium:<input  id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" maxlength="255" name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" size="20" type="text" /><br>

GA Source:<input  id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" maxlength="255" name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" size="20" type="text" /><br>

GA Campaign:<input  id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" maxlength="255" name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" size="20" type="text" /><br>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>`
```

Comment: The linked blogpost does not work any more because Universal Analytics does not store campaign data in cookies anymore. I  wrote a fairly extensive tutorial on how to get the data into salesforce, but that's not a purely clientside solution. Part 1 is here, further parts are linked therein: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-1/.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try your method.